# Check if an URL has got http:// prefix

Tags: ios, http, url, uiwebview, hyperlink

In my application, when the user add an object, can also add a link for this object and then the link can be opened in a webView.
I tried to save a link without http:// prefix, then open it in the webView but that can't open it!
Before webView starts loading, is there a method to check if the URL saved has got http:// prefix? And if it hasn't got it, how can I add the prefix to the URL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `- (BOOL)hasPrefix:(NSString *)aString` method on NSString to see if an NSString containing your URL starts with the http:// prefix, and if not add the prefix.

```
NSString *myURLString = @"www.google.com";
NSURL *myURL;
if ([myURLString.lowercaseString hasPrefix:@"http://"]) {
    myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];
} else {
    myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",myURLString]];
}
```

I'm currently away from my mac and can't compile/test this code, but I believe the above should work.

Comment: This test breaks with "HTTP://www.google.com". It also doesn't support ftp://, even though UIWebView does.

Comment: I think my answer gives sufficient information that Matthew can solve his problem.

Comment: Yes Greg, that's what I'm looking for... I'll support only http protocol because it's the only one that can serve in my app... ;)

Comment: For checking case insensitive prefix use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18264768/1162959

Answer (score 16):

```
NSString * urlString = ...;
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
if (![[url scheme] length])
{
  url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:urlString]];
}
```

Comment: This can be a solution but this method add the http:// to the URL... and if the URL has got http:// what do this method?

Comment: This code adds "http://" to all URLs without a scheme. "http://blah" has the scheme "http", so `[[url scheme] length]` is non-zero and the code leaves the URL as-is.

Answer (score 6):

Better to use the `scheme` property on the `URL` object:

```
extension URL {
    var isHTTPScheme: Bool {
        return scheme?.lowercased().contains("http") == true // or hasPrefix
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835119/1032372")!
if myURL.isHTTPScheme {
    // handle, e.g. open in-app browser:            
    present(SFSafariViewController(url: url), animated: true)
} else if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(myURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(myURL)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an extension for String in Swift, to see if url string got http or https

```
extension String{

    func isValidForUrl()->Bool{

        if(self.hasPrefix("http") || self.hasPrefix("https")){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

if(urlString.isValidForUrl())
    {
      //Do the thing here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is any method to check that but you check it in the code.

try using

```
NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"http://"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    // Add http://
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking for "http://" you'll probably want case-insensitive search:

```
// probably better to check for just http instead of http://
NSRange prefixRange = 
    [temp rangeOfString:@"http" 
                options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];
if (prefixRange.location == NSNotFound)
```

Although I think the url scheme check is a better answer depending on your circumstances, as URLs can begin with http or https and other prefixes depending on what your use case is.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a new category for NSURL: File > New File > Objective-C Category.  You can call the category something along the lines of HTTPURLWithString, make it a category of NSURL, press next and add it to your target.  Then in the NSURL+HTTPURLFromString.m implement the following message (and declare the message in your .h)

```
@implementation NSURL (HTTPURLFromString)
+(NSURL *)HTTPURLFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *searchString = @"http";
    NSRange prefixRange = [string rangeOfString:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSAnchoredSearch)];

    if (prefixRange.length == 4) {
        return [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    }
    return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", string]];

}
@end
```

To open a link in the WebView is simply

```
NSString *urlString = @"www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL HTTPURLFromString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scheme property for check it out. For example...

```
if ([yourURL.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"] || [yourURL.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In function 'navigationAction' of WKNavigationDelegate

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                var urlString = url.absoluteString
                if urlString.lowercased().hasPrefix("http://") == false {
                    urlString = String(format: "http://%@", urlString)
                }

                let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
                presentInFullScreen(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
```