# How to see if an NSString starts with a certain other string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I am trying to check to see if a string that I am going to use as URL starts with http. The way I am trying to check right now doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableString *temp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://"];
if ([businessWebsite rangeOfString:@"http"].location == NSNotFound){
    NSString *temp2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    temp2 = businessWebsite;
    [temp appendString:temp2];
    businessWebsite = temp2;
    NSLog(@"Updated BusinessWebsite is: %@", businessWebsite);
}

[web setBusinessWebsiteUrl:businessWebsite];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Try this: `if ([myString hasPrefix:@"http"])`.

By the way, your test should be `!= NSNotFound` instead of `== NSNotFound`. But say your URL is `ftp://my_http_host.com/thing`, it'll match but shouldn't.

Comment: Yup that was it. I should have noticed the != thing before, but in the end it was the hasPrefix that worked. Thanks for the advice, I'll mark yours as the correct answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 25):

I like to use this method:

```
if ([[temp substringToIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
  //starts with http
}
```

or even easier:

```
if ([temp hasPrefix:@"http"]) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thats good too. This way is a little more flexible as well, thanks for the comment

Comment: This will crash if temp string is less than 5 characters. Index starts at 0. So this is not a good answer. Also, the example has a character count mismatch: "http" does not have 5 characters. Case insensitivity should also be considered.

Comment: @Daniel What are you even saying? Why 5? This is not an NSArray... Index 4 is the 4th character not the 5th! And have you EVER seen Http or hTtP? Case sensitive is not relevant. Also the question was about checking if the string begins with http not about the string being shorter than 4 characters. hasPrefix: is better but this works just as well. Stop whining

Comment: @JonasG - Yes, you are correct about the behavior of substringToIndex. Note, however, index 4 is actually the 5th character; index 0 is the first character. I had mistakenly assumed that substringToIndex includes the character specified by the index, but it does not. Case sensitivity is relevant when user input is involved, which I believe the question hints at. Consider the case of "HTTP://WWW...". But the biggest problem is that the proposed solution will throw an exception when it encounters "ftp" or a string less than 4 characters. The hasPrefix method does not have the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you're checking for "http:" you'll probably want case-insensitive search:

```
NSRange prefixRange = 
    [temp rangeOfString:@"http" 
                options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];
if (prefixRange.location == NSNotFound)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift version:**

```
if line.hasPrefix("#") {
  // checks to see if a string (line) begins with the character "#"
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted... this is the simple Swift way of doing this.  Most new iOS developers are probably going to be using Swift from here on out, and the OP never said that only Objective-C answers were requested.

Comment: "I don't know why this was down-voted"- probably because the syntax is wrong? Should be `if line.hasPrefix("prefix")` {}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a simpler syntax, but placing () around an if statement isn't bad syntax.  For some of us old timers, it reads more clearly, and works exactly the same.  `if (line.hasPrefix("#")) {}` works just as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution to the problem. It will remove the letters that are not necessary and is case insensitive.

```
    - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self generateSectionTitles];
}

-(NSArray *)generateSectionTitles {

    NSArray *alphaArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *character in alphaArray) {



        if ([self stringPrefix:character isInArray:self.depNameRows]) {
            [sectionArray addObject:character];
        }

    }

    return sectionArray;

}

-(BOOL)stringPrefix:(NSString *)prefix isInArray:(NSArray *)array {

    for (NSString *str in array) {

        //I needed a case insensitive search so [str hasPrefix:prefix]; would not have worked for me.
        NSRange prefixRange = [str rangeOfString:prefix options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];
        if (prefixRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            return TRUE;
        }

    }

    return FALSE;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    NSInteger newRow = [self indexForFirstChar:title inArray:self.depNameRows];
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:0];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

    return index;
}

// Return the index for the location of the first item in an array that begins with a certain character
- (NSInteger)indexForFirstChar:(NSString *)character inArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (NSString *str in array) {

        //I needed a case insensitive search so [str hasPrefix:prefix]; would not have worked for me.
        NSRange prefixRange = [str rangeOfString:character options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];
        if (prefixRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            return count;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```