# Detect hashtags including & in hashtag

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can detect hashtags like this.

```
+ (NSArray *)getHashArrayWithInputString:(NSString *)inputStr
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)" options:0 error:&error];

    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:inputStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, inputStr.length)];
    NSMutableArray *muArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        NSString* word = [inputStr substringWithRange:wordRange];

        NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
        if ([word rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
        {
            // newString consists only of the digits 0 through 9
        }
        else
        [muArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@",word]];
    }
    return muArr;
}
```

Problem is that if inputStr is "#D&D", it can detect only #D. How shall I do?

Comment: it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934688/how-to-see-if-an-nsstring-starts-with-a-certain-other-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that with your reg expression add special character that you want allow.

```
#(\\w+([&]*\\w*)*) //To allow #D&D&d...

#(\\w+([&-]*\\w*)*) //To allow both #D&D-D&...
```

Same way you add other special character that you want.

So simply change your regex like this.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+([&]*\\w*)*)" options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: What about `D&D&D`? :) Hint, parenthesis will help.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanx for the suggestion, Edit answer for that also.

Comment: Could you please show me what pattern should I use to detect "@" and only numbers after it?

Answer (score 1):

I was using this lib:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/twitter-text

There is TwitterText class with method 
`(NSArray *)hashtagsInText:(NSString *)text checkingURLOverlap (BOOL)checkingURLOverlap` It could help.

I used this pod year ago last time, then it worked great. For today you need to check if it is still ok. Let me know :) Good luck