# Add http:// prefix to UITextField in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, uitextfield, prefix

If a user omits this prefix in browser the page will not load
Anyone knows how to add http:// prefix to UITextField if user omits it?
thanks

Comment: Take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789126/check-if-an-url-has-got-http-prefix/3789436#3789436

Comment: Thanks for reply,but i want in swift language not objective c

Answer (score 2):

i've checked the previous answers for objective-c solutions, and i thought to do it in the simple way: 
add the prefix if it's not there in the textfield, using "hasprefix":

```
 if(!textField.text!.hasPrefix("http://")){
       textField.text =  "http://" + textField.text!
    }
```

there's corner here which is https case, but this will fix the current situation.